# Corrupted and split TCP frames

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, kernel

We're running a HTTP server, written in Go, behind a loadbalancer. After a random amount of requests (every few hundred million), a request is somehow split into two packets and the second packet is missing the first byte.

We've analyzed the code for our server library, fasthttp, and for Go and we haven't found anything that can explain this behavior.

Next we captured a lot of these requests with tcpdump, they're not split - the entire request is inside one TCP packet, and they look correct.

Still, the Go server thinks there are two packets, and strace confirms that the socket is being read twice:

```
2289 23:09:37.239558 read(212, "GET /json HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/x-stream\r\nAccept: application/x-stream\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\r\nUser-Agent: Java/Android\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nKeep-Alive: 5000\r\nHttp-version: HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: <snipsnip>\r\nX-TCPI: 91", 4096) = 229
32289 23:09:37.239620 read(212, "217.26.11   \r\n\r\n", 3867) = 16
```

So we're thinking it's either the loadbalancer, in which case tcpdump somehow is modifying the packets to look correct, or it's the kernel.

Where should we look next?

Answer (score 3):

> Still, the Go server thinks there are two packets ...

This is the wrong interpretation. The Go server reads from a TCP socket. A TCP socket has no notion of packets, it only sees a byte stream. How the byte stream is packaged during transport does not matter at all, i.e. a single read might be the result of a single packet or of multiple  packets or even a half packet etc. Similar the TCP stack might put multiple writes into a single packet or might also spread a single write over multiple packets.

An application which assumes that a specific packaging will be done, that a single read will match a single packet or that a write on the sender will result in exactly a read at the recipient, is wrong. It might work most of the time but it might break suddenly if used in a different context, with more load on the machine, different sizes of socket buffers etc. Such wrong assumptions usually result in hard to trigger and hard to debug issues.

> ... a request is somehow split into two packets **and the second packet is missing the first byte**. ... Where should we look next?

Please check with a packet capture if this byte went missing before the data reached the server or if it is inside your code. Depending on where the data got corrupted you either need to fix your code or you need to fix whatever is in front of your server and corrupted the data.  It might even be a broken client. You might narrow down the cause of the problem by strategically doing packet captures at various places in the network.

Comment: As mentioned, captured packets with tcpdump (on the same machine with the Go server) show that the data that reaches the server is correct, including the missing byte.

Comment: @Vlad: While you might have captured the data at the physical server you should capture the data directly before your HTTP server (i.e. after the load balancer) to narrow down the cause of the problem. And while not totally impossible I find it very unlikely that this is a kernel problem. Given how many use the kernel without problems compared to how many use your self-made HTTP server it is way more likely that the problem is in your own code (or the load balancer).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain clearly enough. The load balancer is not on the same machine, it's sending these packets via the network to the Go server.

Comment: @Vlad: I see. Since `tcpdump` is pretty sure not *"...somehow is modifying the packets to look correct,"* and it is way more unlikely that the kernel is more buggy than your application I suspect that your self-made HTTP server is the actual problem. Again, reading twice should not be a problem.

Comment: I assumed the read() calls captured by strace prove that the "self-made HTTP server" ([fasthttp](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp)) is not the issue.

Comment: @Vlad: You only show a selected snippet of the strace output. You also don't show the matching packet capture. Thus one can currently only rely on your interpretation of what you see. Again, a kernel issue is very unlikely.